# Move SQL Server 2008 to virtual machine

Tags: license, sql-server-2008

I have a physical server that uses SQL server 2008 in managing my warehouse.

We desperately want to virtualize this server.

Would I need to buy a new SQL server license? Or is there a way to use the same license when we move from physical to a virtual environment?

Comment: I guess you don't need a new one!

Comment: Your license allows for one single instance of SQL Server 2008.  It does not matter if its an instance on a guest operating system or on the host operating system itself.

Comment: What if I no longer know the license key? How do I move the license from Physical to Virtual server?

Comment: There are programs to extract the information without the key it cannot be transfered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is normal SQL Server License (not some kind of OEM) - I think you can use your SQL Server 2008 on virtual machine (according to [this article on TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/peeyusht/archive/2010/03/19/sql-licensing-under-virtualization.aspx)).

Microsoft licensing mechanisms are complicated, I think you should call to Microsoft and ask about this for reliable information.

**SQL Server registration data**  is stored in registry, here:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Registration
```

Technically - you can backup that registry part and restore it on virtual machine, however I'm not sure if this is not license violation. Maybe you should call to Microsoft and ask if you can use product if you lost your key.